# Force user to logout session PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication, logout

I can't seem to find a straightforward answer to this question. Is there a way in which I can force a logged in user to logout? My login system essentially just relies on a session containing the user's unique ID (which is stored in a mysql database). So essentially just...

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
echo "You're logged in!";
} else {
echo "You need to login!";
}
```

But let's say I want to ban this user, well I can change their status to banned in my database but this won't do anything until the user logs out and attempts to log back in... So, how do I force this user to logout? Preferably without checking every single time they view a page whether or not their status has been switched to "banned" because that seems like unnecessary stress on my server. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: why not check if user is banned during login process..?

Comment: I do check during the login process, but if they don't logout they can continue using the site despite being banned... I'm obviously banning them for a reason, I don't want to just wait until they're kind enough to log themselves out.

Comment: Ian, have you found the solution after all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you need to check every time they load a page, or possibly look at an Ajax call at set intervals to check their status from the DB.

Then you can use `session_destroy();` to end their session. This will destroy their entire session.

Otherwise you can use `unset($_SESSION['user_id']);` to unset a single session variable

Comment: Hmm, ajax is an interesting idea but a skilled user would likely be able to block the call.

Answer (score 6):

> Preferably without checking every single time they view a page whether or not their status has been switched to "banned" because that seems like unnecessary stress on my server.

Loading the user from the database on every page load, rather than storing a copy of the user in the session, is a perfectly reasonable solution. It also prevents the user from getting out of sync with the copy in the database (so that, for instance, you can change a user's properties or permissions without them having to log out and back in).

Comment: +1.  "seems like unnecessary stress on my server." = premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this on every page...

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

    $sql = "SELECT from tbl where status='banned' and user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'] ";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if(!empty(mysql_num_rows($query))){ // found the banned user
       //redirect to logout or
       //session_destroy();
    }

} else {
echo "You need to login!";
}
```

*if the user is still logged in... check if his/her status is banned or not... if banned.. then logout*

Answer (score 0):

You can unset it.

```
unset($_SESSION['user_id'])
```

Comment: I think you misread my question, I know how to unset sessions what I don't know how to do is force a user to unset their session, without referencing the database every time.

Comment: I guess you want to know if you can unset an arbitrary session. The answer is no. The PHP script that serves them a page needs to query to see if they're banned. You should be querying the DB for their basic user info every time the page renders, anyway, in case they change it somehow, so just check if they're banned and unset if so.

Comment: Hmm, so I should reset the session variables every time the page renders? I reset the needed session variables if they change them (say they change their username, which is stored in a session variable), is there a specific security (or other) reason I should be checking every time the page loads that I don't know about?

Comment: Yes- It's the only way to do this. You can't, in PHP, say "unset this persons session", unless the page is being served to that person, and because the banning is done in a page that's being sent to YOU, you can only put it in a database and wait for them to read from it. It's simply impossible any other way.

Comment: Alright, I'm going to leave this unanswered for a few hours just to be sure, but if nothing comes up I'll select you for best answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem.

There are other ways to do it without a DB, but it's still going to stress the server a tiny amount, and the DB is the simplest method. You can maintain a flat file, for example, of all banned usernames, but it doesn't scale well. In any case, you have to put the value somewhere from your ban page, and read it from the serving page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Custom Session Handlers](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) this way you have full control where and how the session data is stored on the server.

So you could store the session data for a particular user in a file called `<user_id>.session` for example. Then, to logout the user, just delete that file.

Comment: Huh, well that's certainly good to know. Unfortunately my localhost program (MAMP) hasn't launched support for PHP 5.4 yet so I think I'm going to put looking into this solution off until that happens. Thank you.

Comment: Also this solution slows down every page by executing PHP during every cycle of a session's life which would normally be handled by pre-compiled code.

Comment: @Ian: This even works with PHP4 (see: [session_set_save_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)) only the new [SessionHandlerInterface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php) needs PHP >=5.4.0 thats just another way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls in an interval will put extra load on server. If you want real-time response to your actions(e.g. the user will be signed out right when you ban them from your system backend), then you should look into something like [`Server Push`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push).

The idea is to keep a tunnel open from Server to Browser whenever a user is browsing your website, so that you can communicate with them from server-side too. If you want them to be banned, push a logout request and the process that in your page(i.e. force logout by unsetting session).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me am using pHP 5.4
    include 'connect.php';

```
  session_start();
  if(session_destroy())
  {
     header("Location: login.php");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session_save_path()` to find the path where PHP saves the session files, and then delete them using `unlink()`.

Once you delete the session file stored in the sever, the client side `PHPSESSID` cookie will no longer be valid for authentication and the user will be automatically be logger out of your application.

Please be very careful while using this approach, if the path in question turns out to be the global /tmp directory! There's bound to be other processes other than PHP storing temporary data there. If PHP has its own directory set aside for session data it should be fairly safe though.

Answer (score -1):

There is a few ways to do this the best in my opinion based on security is:
NOTE: THIS IS REALLY ROUGH.... I know the syntax is wrong, its just for you to get an idea.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","sampleuser","samplepass");
if (!$con)
{
$error = "Could not connect to server";
}
mysql_select_db("sampledb", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sampletable` WHERE `username`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
$userdeets = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($_SESSION['sessionvalue'] != $userdeets['sessionvalue'])
{
session_destroy();
Header('Location: logout.php');
}
else
{
$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `sessionvalue` WHERE `username`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' SET `sessionvalue` = RANDOMVALUE''");
 $sesval = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
$_SESSION['sessionvalue'] = $seshval
}
```

Now I know thats not the very code but in essence what you need to do to be secure and have this ability is:

- Everytime a page load check a Session value matches a value in the DB.
- Every time a page loads set a new session value based on a random generated DB value. you will need to store the username in a session as well.
- if the Session ID's do not match then you destroy the session and redirect them.
- if it does match you make the new session ID.

if you want to ban a user you can set their sessionvalue in the DB to a value like "BANNED". this value will not allow them to log in either. this way you can control user through a simple web form and you can also generate list of banned users very easily etc etc.  I wish I had more time to explain it I hope this helps.