# logged out from a site in all browsers if password have been changed in php

Tags: php, session, browser, logout

when a user logged-in with same credentials on different browser. Once user change password in one browser then on other browser user should be automatically logged-out and redirect to sign in page with some notifications

how this can be achieved ?

Comment: Most sites would not let you be logged in om multiple devices at once

Comment: Here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407555/force-user-to-logout-session-php

Answer (score 1):

The exact implementation depends on your seesion-keeping details, but the basic idea is incorporate a hash of the user's password (and possibly also a count of number-of-password-changes) in the data used to generate a session cookie. Then, when the user changes their password, other sessions, dependant on a stale hash, will no longer be valid. Then just add something like "you changed your password, invalidating any existing sessions" to your 'reasons why you need to log in again' error page.

Comment: @SaifAlvi, beyond uselessly-generic stuff like `sess = sha2( uname + logintime + pwhash )`, not really; it is too dependant on the details of how you are generating seesion cookies in the first place.